# Storyboard won't load

Tags: ios, storyboard

I copied a storyboard from one project to another and now I am getting an error when I try to load it.

[image]

Any ideas? I am not missing any view controllers. What would prevent a storyboard from being able to load?

I really hope I don't have to rebuild the whole thing. It's quite a large one.

> 8/20/14 11:03:07.032 AM Xcode[25482]:  DVTAssertions: Warning in /SourceCache/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport-5069/Xcode3Core/LegacyProjects/Frameworks/DevToolsCore/DevToolsCore/SpecificationTypes/BuiltInSpecifications/Compilers/XCGccMakefileDependencies.m:76
>   Details:  Failed to load dependencies output contents from ``/Users/rsmith/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Tatyana-cddwympaoafzixdpzoffsonzpsyb/Build/Intermediates/Tatyana.build/Debug-iphoneos/Tatyana.build/Objects-normal/armv7s/LoginViewController.d''. Error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “LoginViewController.d” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo=0x7f92323dd8f0 {NSFilePath=/Users/rsmith/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Tatyana-cddwympaoafzixdpzoffsonzpsyb/Build/Intermediates/Tatyana.build/Debug-iphoneos/Tatyana.build/Objects-normal/armv7s/LoginViewController.d, NSUnderlyingError=0x7f923074c2f0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory"}. User info: {
>       NSFilePath = "/Users/rsmith/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Tatyana-cddwympaoafzixdpzoffsonzpsyb/Build/Intermediates/Tatyana.build/Debug-iphoneos/Tatyana.build/Objects-normal/armv7s/LoginViewController.d";
>       NSUnderlyingError = "Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 \"The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. No such file or directory\"";
>   }.
>   Function: void XCGccMakefileDependenciesParsePathsFromRuleFile(NSString *__strong, void (^__strong)(NSString *__strong))
>   Thread:   {name = (null), num = 190}
>   Please file a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.

I commented out the section for that view and I now get this

> 8/20/14 11:12:27.837 AM Xcode[25482]: Exception raised while unarchiving document objects - *** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil

Comment: Check the console and post whatever's in there.

Comment: I don't see anything in the console at all

Comment: Are you looking in the Console app on your Mac or the Xcode console?

Comment: I am looking in Xcode

Comment: Check in Console.app (go to Launchpad -> Utilities) for the log associated with Xcode.

Comment: Thanks! I just edited my post with the log

Answer (score 2):

Instead of copying the whole storyboard you could simply select all views (open the storyboard inside the original project) by clicking inside the storyboard, press `cmd + c` and paste with `cmd + v` inside the new one. your segues and all should be copied as well

Comment: For various reasons I don't have access to that original project anymore, so that won't be an option. Otherwise a great idea though!

Comment: did you choose it as main storyboard in the general project settings?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the way I ended up solving the issue was by opening the storyboard as source and then copying all of the "scene" elements from the original into an empty storyboard.

Comment: That actually was pretty close to my idea

Comment: Yeah, I realized that. One of the reasons I up voted your suggestion.